# How to press back button return to activitymap.xml from "complete action using" menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good day everyone, my project currently could not press back button return from the "complete action using" menu. Does anyone faced this problems before?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        manual_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txt_manual);




        manual_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://community.ump.edu.my/ecomstaff/logginat2.jap");
                                              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                                              startActivity(intent);
                                          }
                                      });   
    }
```

Comment: `i am having some error` We would be appropriated if you told us what is the error!

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)